# Кнопка удаления Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Помогите сделать кнопку удаления(на фотографиях показан как красный символ "X")
Как бы не пробовал, всё равно не так

[image]

[image]

```js
$(function() {
    var $tasksList = $("#tasksList");
    var $taskImput = $("#taskImput");
    var $notification = $("#notification");
    var $description = $("#description");


    var displayNotification = function() {
        if (!$tasksList.children().length) {
            $list.fadeIn("fast");
        } else{
            $list.css("display", "none")
        }
    }

    $("#add-button").on("click" , function() {
        if (!$taskImput.val()) {return false;}

        $notification.remove();

        $tasksList.append("<div class='note'><div class='name'>" + $taskImput.val() + "<button class='delete'>&#10006</button></div><p class='desc'>" + $description.val() + "</p></div>");
    
        $taskImput.val("");

        $description.val("");

        displayNotification();

        $(".delete").on("click", function(){
            var $parent = $(this).parent().parent();
            $parent.remove();
        });

    });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 1000px;
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.fixed-container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#central-conteiner {
  margin-top: 65px;
}

#to-do-list {
  float: left;
}

#add-case {
  float: right;
}

#menu-adding {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  width: 420px;
  height: 500px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  color: #8993ad;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#notification {
  margin-top: 80px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #8993ad;
}

#taskImput {
  height: 45px;
  width: 372px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 14px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

#description {
  width: 372px;
  height: 205px;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-top: 21px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  resize: none;
}

#add-button {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 224px;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: #2174fd;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.note {
  width: 470px;
  height: 135px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
  .name {
    font-weight: normal;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
  }

  .desc {
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #8993ad;
  }

  .delete {
    margin-left: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 24px;
    width: 36px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Список дел</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="central-conteiner">
    <div class="fixed-container">
        <aside id="to-do-list">
            <h2>Список дел</h2>
            <div id="notification">Список пуст...</div>
            <ul id="tasksList"></ul>
        </aside>
        <aside id="add-case">
            <h2>Добавить новое дело</h2>
            <div id="menu-adding">
                * Название<br>
                <input type="text" name="note" id="taskImput"><br>
                * Описание<br>
                <textarea id="description"></textarea><br>
                <button id="add-button">Добавить дело</button>
            </div>
        </aside>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ругается консоль на эту переменную `$list`.
Удалять `$("#notification")` нет необходимости. Можно просто скрывать.
А показывать только при проверке на пустой список дел. Вызывать проверку можно при удалении `.note`
В целом функцию `displayNotification` можно упростить.
Также Вы каждый раз вешаете обработчик на все элементы с классом `.delete`.
То есть повторно на уже созданные элементы, это не так критично, но копить их точно не стоит. Поэтому можно назначать ID вашим записям и назначть обработчик на конкретный элемент.

```
$(function() {
    var $tasksList = $("#tasksList");
    var $taskImput = $("#taskImput");
    var $notification = $("#notification");
    var $description = $("#description");


    var displayNotification = function() {
        if ($('.note').length == 0) {
          $notification.fadeIn("fast");
        }        
    }
    
    const getId = () => {      
      return ($('.note').length == 0) ? 1 : +$('.note').last().attr('id') + 1;
    }

    $("#add-button").on("click" , function() {
        if (!$taskImput.val()) {return false;}        
        $notification.hide();        
        let id = getId();
        $tasksList.append("<div id="+id+" class='note'><div class='name'>" + $taskImput.val() + "<button class='delete'>&#10006</button></div><p class='desc'>" + $description.val() + "</p></div>");
    
        $taskImput.val("");
        $description.val("");        

        $(`#${id} .delete`).on("click", function(){            
          $(`#${id}`).remove();
          displayNotification();
        });

    });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
    var $tasksList = $("#tasksList");
    var $taskImput = $("#taskImput");
    var $notification = $("#notification");
    var $description = $("#description");


    var displayNotification = function() {
        if ($('.note').length == 0) {
          $notification.fadeIn("fast");
        }        
    }
    
    const getId = () => {      
      return ($('.note').length == 0) ? 1 : +$('.note').last().attr('id') + 1;
    }

    $("#add-button").on("click" , function() {
        if (!$taskImput.val()) {return false;}        
        $notification.hide();        
        let id = getId();
        $tasksList.append("<div id="+id+" class='note'><div class='name'>" + $taskImput.val() + "<button class='delete'>&#10006</button></div><p class='desc'>" + $description.val() + "</p></div>");
    
        $taskImput.val("");
        $description.val("");        

        $(`#${id} .delete`).on("click", function(){            
          $(`#${id}`).remove();
          displayNotification();
        });

    });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 1000px;
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.fixed-container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#central-conteiner {
  margin-top: 65px;
}

#to-do-list {
  float: left;
}

#add-case {
  float: right;
}

#menu-adding {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  width: 420px;
  height: 500px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  color: #8993ad;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#notification {
  margin-top: 80px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #8993ad;
}

#taskImput {
  height: 45px;
  width: 372px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 14px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

#description {
  width: 372px;
  height: 205px;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-top: 21px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  resize: none;
}

#add-button {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 224px;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: #2174fd;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.note {
  width: 470px;
  height: 135px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
  .name {
    font-weight: normal;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
  }

  .desc {
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #8993ad;
  }

  .delete {
    margin-left: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 24px;
    width: 36px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Список дел</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="central-conteiner">
    <div class="fixed-container">
        <aside id="to-do-list">
            <h2>Список дел</h2>
            <div id="notification">Список пуст...</div>
            <ul id="tasksList"></ul>
        </aside>
        <aside id="add-case">
            <h2>Добавить новое дело</h2>
            <div id="menu-adding">
                * Название<br>
                <input type="text" name="note" id="taskImput"><br>
                * Описание<br>
                <textarea id="description"></textarea><br>
                <button id="add-button">Добавить дело</button>
            </div>
        </aside>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде несколько ошибок.

1. В `$('#to-do-list').append(...)`, вы пытаетесь добавить что-то в элемент, который не существует. Вместо `#to-do-list`, должно быть `#list`.
2. `$('#name')` и `$('#note-text')` идентифицируют элементы по их `id`. В вашем случае, вы хотите их идентифицировать по `class`, поэтому используйте `$('#list .note:last .name')`.
3. Линия `$('#list').remove();` стирает всё в списке. Не думаю, что это то, что вы хотите. Используйте флаг (переменную `true`/`false`) которая будет определять, есть ли что-то в списке. Или пишите вот так:

   ```
   <div id="list">
       <div id="empty">Список пуст...</div>
   </div>
   ```

   ```js
   $('#empty').remove();
   ```